# Как получить токен пользователя для Firebase?

Tags: python, django, firebase, push-уведомления

Поставили задачу: сделать на сайте пуш-уведомления через *Firebase*. Сказали следующее:

> Для отправки нужны `push_token` пользователя, которому отправляешь, и
>   `token` для сервера, берется он при регистрации приложения на сайте. Его
>   можно пока захардкодить.

Токен сервера нашел в панели приложения. А вот как взять токен пользователя?

P.S. Сайт написан на *Python 3* и *Django 1.11*.

Answer (score 0):

Так ведь документация же [есть](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup), а еще когда вы создавали веб приложение в системе Firebase вам сразу же выводят окошко где говорят что вот этот вот код надо разместить на странице. Примерно такое:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.3.0/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  // TODO: Replace with your project's customized code snippet
  var config = {
    apiKey: "<API_KEY>",
    authDomain: "<PROJECT_ID>.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "<BUCKET>.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "<SENDER_ID>",
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>
```

Потом собственно читаем документацию по АПИ, [тут](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client) вот все расписано как делать. На [GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/tree/master/messaging) есть готовый пример